# VR Chat World "Information puzzles" 4th room

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I've encountered this puzzle in the VR-Chat world "Information puzzles⁄信息谜题".
It's a puzzle world with different rooms (puzzles) and I'm stuck at the 4th room.

[image]

To advance to the next room you have to use the keyboard to type in the solution. The solution has a maximum of 4 letters and the letter "I" is missing from the keyboard.

So half the problem here is figuring out what you have to do. So far I have tried to find letters in the picture and typing them in in alphabetical order (I'm assuming that A->Z means that you have to type them in in alphabetical order). The solution **isn't**:
ADXZ, ADXY, ACDX

In case I've missed crucial information you can download the game on steam for free and enter this world yourself. The solutions to the first three rooms are "6910", "escape", "1469"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I posted this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/u3f2xd/vr_chat_world_information_puzzles_4th_room_by_%E5%88%80%E6%9C%A8%E6%97%A5/) to get help and apparently answer was ADVX...

Edit:

The hunch I had in the original post was correct. You had to look for letters in the picture and type them in in alphabetical order (that's what A->Z means.). "I" is excluded because it's missing from the input keyboard.

From the "D" and the "X" in the picture we can make the assumption that the letters have to look like on the keyboard ("bold").

My guesses were ADXZ, ADXY, ACDX. Z doesn't work, because you can't find a "bold" Z. Y and C don't work, because you can't find "straight" versions of them like they appear on the keyboard. What I failed to see is that there is a "V" in the "X".

So the solution is ADVX. (I also confirmed this inside the game.)

Here is a picture in case you can't find the letters:

[image]

This is what it looks like after you type in the solution. (A door appears. You can also see the solution in the input field if you zoom in.)

[image]